# Mac App Store - can't save a file

Tags: cocoa, nsbundle, mac-app-store, writetofile

Are there any restrictions as far as saving files when you distribute an app over the Mac App Store?

If I compile and run my app from my computer it works fine - it saves the configuration.

However the version that was downloaded over the Mac App Store is not saving the configuration. I don't even see the config file. Anyone knows what is going on?

This is the code that saves the config:

```
-(void)saveConfig:(id)plist {

    NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString: CONFIG_FILE_NAME];

    NSData *xmlData;
    NSString *error;

    xmlData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList: plist
        format: NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
        errorDescription: &error];
    if(xmlData)
    {
        if (![xmlData writeToFile:path atomically:YES])
            NSLog(@"Failed to write the config file onto the hard drive");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write files to the application bundle directory if you’re targeting the Mac App Store. The bundle is supposed to be immutable.

Consider saving your configuration with `NSUserDefaults` or, if you truly need a separate file, the [officially recommended location](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/WhereToPutFiles.html) is (~)/Library/Application Support. Matt Gallagher wrote a nice post called [Finding or creating the application support directory](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/finding-or-creating-application-support.html) in which he provides a solution that uses standard `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` followed by the executable name.

Comment: The Mac App Store really has nothing to do with it. The app bundle is supposed to be off-limits for writing no matter what. App bundles shouldn't be modifying themselves.

Comment: @Joshua I agree that they shouldn’t. However, technically it is possible to modify the app bundle, and some non-MAS applications do that to dynamically register document types according to the application plugins that have been installed since Launch Services does not support runtime document type registering.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should assume that your application's assets are read-only.  This is true in general, not just for the app store.

If you want to save user settings as a property list, use `NSUserDefaults` instead of modifying files inside the application.  This will "just do the right thing", which is to save preferences to `~/Library/Preferences`.