# OSX: Where to store SQLite file for application?

Tags: cocoa, macos, filesystems

My OSX Cocoa application uses SQLite to manage data. When initializing, I need to specify where the database file will be stored.

What is the standard way of handling this?

This database file is required to run (the app will create it if it doesn't exist), and the data should be persisted for ever, even after software updates if possible.

Where should I store it? Application folder? Support Files?

Thanks

Comment: See also: [Mac App Store - can't save a file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6053551/557219)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The convention is to store it in the Application Support folder. i.e. in `~/Library/Application Support/*YourAppName*/database.db`

You can find the Application Support that you're searching with

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

Comment: Do I manually type the App name or do I dynamically get it somewhere?

Comment: You can use `NSString *appName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleName"];`

Answer (score 2):

In the Application Support folder for your app.

Have a look at the Core Data project setup - which shows how this is usually accomplished by other applications. Or use Core Data for your own application instead of SQLite files.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it should go in the Application Support folder.